# Mutable members should not be stored on ArrayList - Sonar vulnerability

Tags: java, arraylist, sonarqube, code-analysis

I have sonar "Mutable members should not be stored or returned directly" issue in my java class. I have fixed it by below code but still sonar is giving me the same error

```
public class UserInfoImpl
{
    List<UserInfo> userDetails = Collections.emptyList();

    void perform()
    {

            List<UserInfo> userDetails = service.getUserDetails();
            userDetails = new ArrayList<>(userDetails);
            this.userDetails = Collections.unmodifiableList(userDetails);
       
    }

 
    public final List<UserInfo> getUserDetailList()
    {
        return userDetails;  // sonar error happens at this line
    }
}
```

does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

[This rule](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2384) protects against a method being able to change the state of your `UserInfoImpl` instance after calling one of its getter functions.

There are two possibilities:

1. A caller can change the returned list. You have possibly already prevented that by using `Collections.unmodifiableList`, but that is done in a method called `perform()` - how does Sonar know that `perform()` is always called before `getUserDetailList`? Why not return `Collections.unmodifiableList` inside the body of your `getUserDetailList` method?
2. Even if you ensure that the returned list is always unmodifiable, the caller can still modify the `UserInfo` instances contained in the list. To prevent that possibility, ensure that `UserInfo` is unmodifiable, or make a copy of each `UserInfo` that you put into the list returned by `getUserDetailList`.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a reference to `userDetails`. By doing this you break encapsulation which can potentially bring your `UserInfoImpl` class in an inconsistent state. For example when a client (other class that uses your class) calls `clear` on the returned list.

```
// client A
var list = userInfoImpl.getUserDetailList();
list.clear();

// client B
var list = userInfoImpl.getUserDetailList();
list.get(0); // IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Other clients that use the same object can now get unexpected `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

To solve this you can return a copy of the list.

Comment: The core of your explanation is right, but setting it to null doesn't work like that in Java. A different example could be that the external class could add or remove items, which might not be desirable.

Comment: You are right, my apologies. I have updated my answer accordingly.